# I am getting following error while deploying application on google cloud appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

**I am getting following error while deploying application on google cloud appengine
I have downloaded appengine-java-sdk-1.9.42 and installed appengine plugins in netbeans.**

com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: XML error validating 
    
        
        1

```
   <application>driven-copilot-143702</application> 
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
    <threadsafe>false</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
 against C:\Users\graycell\Downloads\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.42\docs\appengine-web.xsd
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils.validateXmlContent(XmlUtils.java:120)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils.validateXml(XmlUtils.java:91)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.<init>(Application.java:227)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.readApplication(Application.java:421)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readWar(AppCfg.java:297)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readApplication(AppCfg.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:119)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:115)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 17; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'application'. One of '{"http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":runtime, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":module, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":service, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":instance-class, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":automatic-scaling, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":manual-scaling, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":basic-scaling, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":static-files, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":resource-files, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":system-properties, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":vm-settings, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":beta-settings, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":vm-health-check, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":health-check, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":resources, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":network, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":env-variables, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":ssl-enabled, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":sessions-enabled, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":async-session-persistence, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":user-permissions, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":public-root, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":inbound-services, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":precompilation-enabled, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":admin-console, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":static-error-handlers, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":warmup-requests-enabled, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":threadsafe, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":auto-id-policy, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":code-lock, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":vm, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":env, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":class-loader-config, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":url-stream-handler, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":use-google-connector-j, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":api-config}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.StreamValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils.validateXmlContent(XmlUtils.java:116)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `<version>` tag in your appengine-web.xml? Could you show your complete xml file?
Here's the reference doc for your xml: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref

By the way: People are downvoting you because it's much better to try to explain what you've tried instead of just showing a stacktrace. It makes it much harder to help you this way.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i will keep in mind , I am able to solve this error. I have modified appengine-web.xml and it worked 

Now I am getting this error when I deploy my application on appengine server

Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=driven-copilot-143702&version=1&
403 Forbidden
You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~driven-copilot-143702').